# Search Builder Issue

Tags: search-builder

I have  a problem with Search Builder on my CiviCRM.
I just wanted to check how many contacts i have in my db outside of Italy.
It should be a simple search:

1. Record Type = Contacts
2. Field type = Country
3. Operator = ≠
4. Value = Italy

I get this error: "Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
DB Error: no such field". If i try with another field type, e.g. city, it works.

I've tried the same search in CiviCRM Beta website, it works.

Is there someone who can help me figuring out what could be the problem here?

Thank you very much
Alessandro

Comment: taking it as given that you do have records that have Italy, and ones that have a country other than Italy. The search will not return results with Null or Empty in country field.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you would need to find the country_id for Italy in civicrm_country, and then use that? The country name will not be stored in any other table.

Comment: i have marked this down since the original post basically says "i tried this on demo and it works fine" - and I retested and yes you can select ≠ and select the country from the dropdown.